# Multipart file upload in Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, multipartform-data

I have been trying to upload a file on my Scala Play server. I have followed the tutorial given on
[Play framework documentation page dealing with file uploads](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaFileUpload). Following the instructions provided there, I have first created a HTML page called `fileuploadform.scala.html` in the `views` folder. The file hosts the following code

```
@helper.form(action = routes.ScalaFileUploadController.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

<input type="file" name="picture">

<p>
    <input type="submit">
</p>

}
```

Then, I have created two actions in controller. One will honor the GET request to load the `fileuploadform` html and the other will honor the POST request upon click of the Upload button on form.

The two actions in the controller (`ScalaFileUploadController.scala`) are:

```
def uploadForm = Action {
    Ok(views.html.fileuploadform())
  }
```

and

```
  def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
      val filename = Paths.get(picture.filename).getFileName
      picture.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"/path/to/location/$filename"), replace = true)
      Ok("File uploaded")
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.ScalaFileUploadController.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
  }
```

Finally, in the routes, I have defined the routing as

```
GET  /uploadForm                    controllers.ScalaFileUploadController.uploadForm
POST /upload                        controllers.ScalaFileUploadController.upload()
```

The application is running on port xxxx

When I hit the url `ip.ip.ip.ip:xxxx/uploadForm`, I get a COMPILATION ERROR

```
not found: value Paths
```

And the line `val filename = Paths.get(picture.filename).getFileName` gets highlighted.

Am I missing some library that is to be added or some syntax modification?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the following:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths
```